# Angular: Load HTML code that may contain scripts

Tags: angular

I'm quite new to Angular (Have been working with AngularJS for a while). I'm currently facing an issue that I think it can not be solved on the client side:

My Angular app calls a REST service on my server. The server returns a lot of data and some of them are HTML code that may contain  tag with src set to some url.

Will my Angular App load the src scripts?

Comment: does it include the files and add them as links or are the scripts in script tags in the html?

Comment: They will be as follows:
<script src="config.js"></script>
The script will be available on the server. It may or may not be hosted on this server.

Comment: The HTML you get from your REST server - are you trying to then display that HTML (including the `<script>` tags) in your Angular client?

Comment: I want to display the HTML I get from the REST server, but I also need to load the scripts it contains.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Angular removes script tags - https://angular.io/guide/security#sanitization-example

However, there are some `bypassSecurity` functions which may override this although I have never needed to try them. Read up on it here:

https://angular.io/guide/security#direct-use-of-the-dom-apis-and-explicit-sanitization-calls

https://angular.io/guide/security#bypass-security-apis